# Free form circuit resources

Tags: circuit-design

I am fascinated by free form circuit (I hope it's the right name): circuit that does not require a pcb.
Does anyone know some resources about that?

Comment: The name is usually Rat's Nest, and they're great for whacking something together quickly. Unfortunately they are more or less un-repairable, totally un-duplicatable, and somewhat wanting on the robustness front. Use wisely.

Comment: Wasn't this favoured by EEs of the Bob Pease / Jim Williams era? If you look in the low-numbered App Notes by Linear Technology (esp 47) there's some good examples. The combination of ground plane and air dielectric makes them work surprisingly well for high-frequency analog work.

Comment: aka "dead bug" style

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248354/are-circuit-boards-necessary - nice pictures in there.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, maybe? (pad)

[image]

Comment: ... or like [this](http://www.computerhistory.org/atchm//wp-content/uploads/2012/08/williams-thermometer-sculpture.jpg)  (originally from [here](http://www.computerhistory.org/atchm/an-analog-life-remembering-jim-williams/))